# Why does sudo update-grub show multiple versions of the same kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have been running Ubuntu for years now but I am one of those users that thank the stars that Ubunutu 'just works'! I am having a problem which I find hard to put into a search.

I upgraded to 17.10 last night. I found that

```
uname -r
```

returns kernel version 4.2.0-16-generic. It appears the current kernel version for 17.10 should be 4.13.0-16. I can see about 30 kernel versions when I run

```
dpkg --list
```

however when I try to delete an older one it tells me it cannot find it.
The only other posts I can find refer to things that seem above my head.   I did find a couple of commands that show output which may be helpful.

```
sudo update-grub

Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
done

ls -la /etc/grub.d

total 124
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 28 09:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 155 root root 12288 Oct 28 09:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   533 Oct 28 09:19 40_custom_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   735 Oct 28 09:19 41_linux_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   127 Oct 28 09:19 42_debian_theme_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  9783 Mar 30  2017 43_header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   121 Oct 28 09:19 44_custom_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   127 Oct 28 09:19 45_debian_theme_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   691 Oct 28 09:19 46_linux_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   533 Oct 28 09:19 47_custom_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   690 Oct 28 09:19 48_linux_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11281 Mar 30  2017 49_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   265 Oct 28 09:19 50_memtest86+_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12059 Mar 30  2017 51_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1418 Oct 14  2015 52_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   533 Oct 28 09:19 53_custom_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   736 Oct 28 09:19 54_linux_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   121 Oct 28 09:19 55_custom_proxy
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Dec  9  2015 backup
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec  9  2015 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 28 09:19 proxifiedScripts
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 Oct 14  2015 README
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   362 Oct 28 09:19 .script_sources.txt
```

Apparently something is not right.  I was using Grub Customizer to try to get 17.10 to load with 4.13.0-16 instead of 4.2.0-16 which

```
uname -r
```

says I am running.

```
lsb_release -a
```

says I have 17.10

See comment below - this is similar to two other posts but both include references to permissions and removal - neither of which I am familiar with or are sure what values to use safely.  Nor can I tell which entry I should do something with even if I did.

Comment: You don't need to use grub-customizer. Simply choose the kernel you want at the grub menu. If you don't see the grub menu, then hold the SHIFT key down during boot.

Comment: I think I am seeing the grub menu....I see several rows - some say 10.10, some say 15.10 and there are entries for recovery and memtest.  There are also several 'Advanced' entries.   When I choose one of those I get three versions of the same kernel but I see no entries to let me choose the 4.13.0 kernel.  The entries also refer to sda5 and sda6 - which I presume are two partitions.  I boot to 15.10 on sda6 and get a 17.10 OS.